# C# Xamarin How to store Listview data?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, listview, xamarin, menu

I have an `Android` app which retrieves data from a json string, and add it to a `ListView`. Now I have created a menu with multiple pages, but when I have a filled `ListView` and swap between pages and come back at the `ListView` IT IS EMPTY!!!

I can't find anything on google about this, can someone tell me how to store the `ListView` data or something?

```
        var propertyList = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<products>>(property.ToString());

        //Parse json content
        var jObject = JObject.Parse(json);

        var coinPropery = jObject["Products"] as JArray;

        mItems = new List<product>();

        foreach (var property in coinPropery)
        {
            //Convert every value in Array to string
            var propertyList = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<product>>(property.ToString());

            //Add all strings to List
            mItems.AddRange(propertyList);
        }


        //Get all the values from Name, and convert it to an Array
        string[][] NamesArray = mItems.OrderByDescending(i => i.Name)
            .Select(i => new string[] { i.Products, i.Name })
            .Distinct()
            .ToArray();

        foreach (string[] str in NamesArray)
        {
            string Name = str[0];
            string FullName = str[1];
        }
```

In the code above I parse the Json content and add it to a list called product

```
//Add all strings to List
mItems.AddRange(propertyList);

//Fill the DataSource of the ListView with the Array of Names
adapter = new ListViewAdapter(this, mItems);

//Bind DataSource to ListView
ListviewCoins.Adapter = adapter;
```

This is the code where I bind the Adapter to the Listview.

```
private void GraphTab_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // Set view to Main
    SetContentView(Resource.Layout.Graph);
}
```

And this is how I change pages.

Comment: If you want same list to access in multiple pages, then you can make it static, no need to store it in local

Comment: when are you adding the data to the listview? when you say "swap between pages", are you creating a new instance of the page with the listview or just re-displaying the existing page?

Comment: Fahadsk what do you mean with make static, I can't find anything like that on the Internet. I created a list with all the data, and after that I bind my list as adapter to the Listview.

Comment: Please add your code for better understanding.

Comment: Can you help me with this code Fahadsk?